# Конфликты скриптов

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как устранить конфликт библиотек jquery ui, jquery 1.11.00?
Имеется код хедера

```
<script src="1.6.1-jquery.min.js"></script>
```

И скрипт ползунка

```
xiper.net/collect/js-plugins/ui/jquery-ui-slider
```

И имеется скрипт

```
$(function().hover(function() { $("body").remove();});
```

Происходит конфликт.

Comment: Откуда взялся конфликт между jQuery и jQuery UI?

Comment: Какая версия jQuery UI и какая версия jQuery?

Comment: Не могу найти как с Вами связаться через лс, весь сайт обшарил)) По сабжу, есть файл скриптов где имеются скрипты аля $(function(){}); и т д они конфликтуют с jquery range

Comment: Это потому что здесь нет ЛС. `document.ready` не может конфликтовать с чем-то из jQuery UI. Добавьте в вопрос пример проблемы или хотя бы **очень подробно** опишите проблему. Скорее всего ошибка в чем-то другом: несовместимость версий, неправильное подключение скриптов, неправильное использование jQuery или jQuery UI.

Comment: Имеется код хедера 
    <script src="1.6.1-jquery.min.js"></script> и скрипт ползунка http://xiper.net/collect/js-plugins/ui/jquery-ui-slider и имеется скрипт $(function().hover(function() { $("body").remove();}); происходит конфликт.

Comment: Да какой уж тут конфликт... `$(function().hover` - это уже некорректный код, синтаксическая ошибка. При этом в данном коде нет даже намёка на jQuery UI.

Comment: Это я примерный код написал, скрипты которые находятся внутри html файла работают если убрать скрипт ползунка

Comment: А зачем нужен примерный, абсолютно неправильный код? Добавьте в вопрос [минимальный, полный, воспроизводимый пример](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) кода, в котором действительно возникает проблема. Сложность тут в том, что ясновидцев на сайте нет.

Answer (score 1):

1. **jQueryUI** должен грузиться после **jQuery** *(глупо, но вдруг)*
2. Выкачайте последние версии библиотек: [jQuery 1.11.3](https://jquery.com/download/) (достаточно) и [jQueryUI 1.11.4](https://jqueryui.com/). Предположительно, у Вас старая **jQueryUI**.
   *Тоже как то не заводился ползунок, помогло (мне) обновление **jQueryUI**.*

**UPD1:**

1. Если Вы только начали писать код, и где то сгуглили пример, то лучше сразу обновите **jQuery** *(см выше)*, а **jquery-ui-slider.js** заменить на **jquery-ui.js** *(см выше)*.
2. Если же код старый, то пора подумать о переходе на свежую версию **jQuery**.
   Или использовать новые библиотеки и **noConflict** хотя бы на страницы с ползунком.

*Ну и конечно же лог ошибки в студию...*